# Semantic HTML5 structure and Google penalty

Tags: html5, microdata

I'm in need for clarity. I'm at an annoying step in my development of a website, and I have read a lot about semantic structure etc, but I'm a bit nervous for my current structure, so I would like to ask your expertise to see, if I might get problems with search engine bots with this setup.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip menuen</a>
    <header class="site-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
        <h1>
            <a class="site-title-link" href="https://crafthouse.dk">
                <svg id="header-logo" class="header-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-labelledby="title desc" viewBox="0 0 158 24.7">
                    <title id="title" itemprop="headline">Brand Name</title>
                    <desc id="desc" itemprop="description">- brand description</desc>
                    <!-- A lot of svg logo code here -->
                </svg> 
            </a>
        </h1>
        <nav itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
            <button id="hamburger-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </button>

            <div id="site-navigation" class="site-navigation">
                <ul class="navigation-list">
                    <li><a class="navigation-link" href="#">page</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navigation-link" href="#">page</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navigation-link" href="#">page</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navigation-link" href="#">page</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navigation-link" href="#">page</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navigation-link" href="#">page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="menu-speciel" class="menu-speciel">
                <div class="nav-btn-wrap">
                    <button id="siteLogin" class="nav-btn">
                        <span class="screen-reader-text">Admin login</span>
                        <svg class="nav-admin-icon nav-icons">
                            <use xlink:href="img/generel/svg-system.svg#admin-icon"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <button id="siteSearch" class="nav-btn">
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Søg</span>
                    <svg class="nav-search-icon nav-icons">
                        <use xlink:href="img/generel/svg-system.svg#search-icon"></use>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main id="content" class="main" itemscope itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPageElement">
         <h2>Main content header</h2> 
    </main>

    <footer itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">

    </footer>
```

In the outline it will look like this:

- Brand name - brand description

  - untitled nav
  - Main content header

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, a heading should contain text, not an image.

Also, somewhat more important from an SEO perspective, the `<h1>` element should relate to the specific page. Unless this site is a single page, having the same `<h1>` on every page would be a very bad idea.

Generally, ranking for the company name is a given (unless the company is called 'Cheap Viagra Cialis Online ltd"...).

I would remove the heading tag from the page header:

```
    <header class="site-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
        <a class="site-title-link" href="https://crafthouse.dk">
            <svg id="header-logo" class="header-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-labelledby="title desc" viewBox="0 0 158 24.7">
                <title id="title" itemprop="headline">Brand Name</title>
                <desc id="desc" itemprop="description">- brand description</desc>
                <!-- A lot of svg logo code here -->
            </svg> 
        </a>
        <nav itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
```

And swap the `<h2>` in the `content` section for an `<h1>`:

```
<main id="content" class="main" itemscope itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPageElement">
     <h1>Main content header</h1> 
</main>
```

Comment: Okay thank you. But doing this will result in "untitled body/document" ind the outliner? I guess I also should remove the schema.org structure in the header?

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML5

If the main content is a self-contained post (like an article or a blog post), you could use the [`article` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-article-element). Otherwise you could use [`section`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-section-element) to make the section that you start with the `h2` explicit.

```html
<main>
  <section> <!-- or <article> -->
    <h2>Main content header</h2> 
  </section>
</main>
```

#### Outline

I think your page structure is great. Using a `header` with an `h1` for the site title makes sense. That way the following sections (`nav`, main content) are in its scope, and you get a nicely labeled outline.

It also makes sense to use an image as the content for `h1`, if that’s the site logo. (`h1` is not required to only contain text, and semantically the alternative text for that image represents it for user agents not capable of processing images).

#### Microdata

Microdata can only be used in HTML5. [`svg`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#svg) is an element from a different namespace, so you [may not](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/56670/17633) use Microdata on the child elements `title` and `desc`.

#### Schema.org

You are using the types [`SiteNavigationElement`](http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement), [`WPHeader`](http://schema.org/WPHeader), [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) and [`WPFooter`](http://schema.org/WPFooter) correctly, but they aren’t really that useful for Web pages. HTML already conveys what these represent (using these types makes sense in non-HTML contexts, if at all). Generally, I would recommend to omit [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) and all of its sub-types.

If you want to keep using `WPHeader`, note that its properties `headline` and `description` would have to be about the header, not the site/page (so these properties typically aren’t useful for `WPHeader` to begin with). These properties should be added to the `WebPage` (which means that they shouldn’t have a different item as parent).

As an alternative for the `mainContentOfPage` property (should you agree to omit it and `WebPageElement`), have a look at the [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) property. As value you can provide an item with a type like [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) or [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) (depending on the page, it can also make sense to use [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person) etc. as value).

Comment: I really appreciate your comment :):) The webpage is basically a branding page for a company. I think i will omit the schema.org. I just understood that it helps Google understand the page, but I might do it the JSON way, to markup business address, phone nr etc.

Good to know with the h1 tag and outline, but does it not confuse Google with all these pages with same h1 tag? Or should we try use a php constant to alter some part of the h1? like this:
Business name - desc, for the frontpage
Business name - about.
etc.

Comment: And when using accessible SVG markup, the title and desc for the SVG becomes a part of the h1 tag in the outline :S Does this matter?

Comment: @MikkelMadsen: You can of course also use Microdata for marking up the business etc.. --- If you go with a site-wider `header` and use a heading for the site name/logo, it would be confusing to have a slightly different heading each case; *because* it’s site-wide, it should be the same on every page of your site. --- For the SVG in `h1`: The name (which is the alternative to the logo, right?) should of course be the textual content of the `h1`: it’s what search engines, blind users etc. get. The description, however, should only be part of the `h1` if the text is included in the image.